# Replace -Inf in dataframe with NA in R

Tags: r, replace, na, infinite

I have a problem in my dataframe.

https://gofile.io/?c=eNeEAL

I have several values with -Inf entries. When I want to use the cor-function, I always get NA because of that. So I want to replace the -Inf with NA before I use the cor-function, but I cant find a way to replace them successfully.

I tried

```
dat[mapply(is.infinite, dat)] <- NA
```

but it did not work.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Do not use external files.  Cut your file down to a small size and include it in the question itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We need to do

```
dat[] <- Map(function(x) replace(x, is.infinite(x), NA), dat)
```

---

Or with `lapply`

```
dat[sapply(dat, is.infinite)] <- NA
```